# When multiple calls are coming in through the Q line, How to show up all calls on the extension simultaneously

Tags: queue, asterisk, freepbx

I want to set up a Q in FreePBX. When multiple calls are coming in through the Q, the agent phone should show all of them simultaneously. I set following options in the Q.

```
Skip Busy Agents: NO
ringinuse: YES
```

But issue not resolved. Another interesting thing is that if I bypass Q (sent call directly to extension), multiple calls will appear at extension.

Answer (score 1):

You phone should support multiple lines.

But purpose of queue is ensure it will not call your phones twice.

You have 2 options

1) Use ringgroup

2) Put two or more ACCOUNTS on each phone and setup autofill=yes and strategy NOT ringall.